# QueryManager to find all documents modifed by current user

Tags: 2010, search-results, query

I'm creating a webpart which derives from `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart` and the purpose of this webpart is to find all documents modified by current user.

I've figured as much as to use the `QueryManager.UserQuery` to some extent but I cannot find any guidance on how the syntax works and what properties are available.

Does anybody have some examples?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a such scenario the following approaches could be considered:

### Override Query

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class MyAggregatedDocuments : Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart
    {


        protected override void ConfigureDataSourceProperties()
        {
            // only perform actions when we are trying to show search results
            // i.e. not when you're in Design Mode
            if (this.ShowSearchResults)
            {
                // call the base web part method
                base.ConfigureDataSourceProperties();

                // get the data source object
                CoreResultsDatasource dataSource = this.DataSource as CoreResultsDatasource;

                // override the query being executed: Documents modified by current user
                dataSource.Query = string.Format("IsDocument:1 AND Author:\"{0}\"",SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name);
            }
        }


    }
```

### Leverage CoreResultsWebPart properties

The following properties could be used to specify query:

[CoreResultsWebPart.AppendedQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.searchresultsbasewebpart.appendedquery.aspx)

[CoreResultsWebPart.FixedQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.searchresultsbasewebpart.fixedquery.aspx)

Example:

```
crwp.AppendedQuery = string.Format("IsDocument:1 AND Author:\"{0}\"",SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name);
```

---

To construct a query by `Modified Date` it is assumed that `Author` managed property is used.

Regarding query syntax, follow [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx) for a more details.